# How to remove a certain element off random range of values?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to randomly generate a double round-robin schedule for several teams, with teams as lines and rounds as columns. Each team is scheduled against every other team twice, once assigned positive value of the oppoent for a match at home, once negative value for a match away.

The code will be kinda like below, except it should work for a 2D array instead of 1D, where certain "K" and "-K" is taken off from possible randomized value of element(team, round) for each line of a 2D array, instead of a fixed value.

K is the #line that makes sure a team does not match itself (eg. make k=+-2's weight=0 in "dist{}" while assigning line #2, so "2" and "-2" will not occur as team 2's assigned opponent for itself, home or away), but this removal should NOT be permanent, since in other lines of the schedule array the team #K is a valid opponent.

Is there a functionality that allows taking a different k off the randomization for each line(team)? Or could I do it with srand()?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
std::random_device rd;

unsigned long seed = rd();
std::cout << "seed " << seed << std::endl;

std::mt19937 engine(seed);

// Distribution  {0, 1, 2, 4, 5}
std::discrete_distribution<> dist {{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}};  // 3 given 0 weight(chance).
auto rng = std::bind(dist, std::ref(engine));

const int n = 10;
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
{
    int x = rng();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_Or could I do it with srand()?_" - `srand()` is seeding `rand()` so no. There's no reason to bring in those functions. You are using the correct library, `<random>`.

Comment: What's being asked here isn't really that obvious, as to me, the title is clearer than the question itself. Consider rewording it to be more specific, yet explicit, about the subject. I'd be happy to upvote it, in that case

Comment: @lenerdv Good call. The question is indeed imprecise. It should be about removing a value equal to the #line of an array, so a team is always assigned teams other than itself to play against.

Comment: oh, got it. yup, it's actually pretty intresting. upvoted :)

Comment: Is your goal to create a schedule for all teams playing against eachother and to display that as rounds? Should each team be playing the other teams twice - once as the home team and once as the away team?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this one

```cpp
std::discrete_distribution<> make_dist(int k, int N)
{
    std::vector<int> dist(N,1);
    dist.at(k) = 0;
    return std::discrete_distribution<>(dist.begin(), dist.end());
}
```

replace your

```cpp
std::discrete_distribution<> dist {{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}};  // 3 given 0 weight(chance).
```

with

```cpp
auto dist = make_dist(3,6);
```

Comment: This will work to remove a fixed value like 0 from randomization results, as I use positive integers 1 -- n for the n teams. But how about removing a not fixed value? Each line have a different value (#line) that needs to be invalidated, while all other values are good to go. So each line should only ignore their respective value "k", while other teams still have access to this value "k" during their assignment?

Comment: @YuChen a loop having `make_dist(k, number_of_teams)`